# How to add ACIs to OpenLDAP properly

Tags: centos, ldap, password, openldap, access-control-list

So I'm trying to get some ACIs added to my OpenLDAP system (hosting on CentOS 6). I've read how others put their ACIs in bdb like so...

```
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by dn="cn=manager,dc=bromosapien,dc=net" write by anonymous auth by self write by * none
olcAccess: to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: to * by dn="cn=manager,dc=bromosapien,dc=net" write by * read
```

However, I want to avoid that and just allow the password changes to happen from a container (and at least avoid using Directory manager). I read someone doing this which works from their perspective:

```
dn: ou=People,dc=bromosapien,dc=net
changetype: modify
add: aci
aci: (targetattr = "userpassword || telephonenumber")(version 3.0; acl "Allow self entry modification"; allow (write)(userdn = "ldap:///self");)
```

Problem is, trying to add it, I get this.

```
# ldapadd -xWD "cn=manager,dc=bromosapien,dc=net" -f aci-password.ldif 
Enter LDAP Password: 
modifying entry "ou=People,dc=bromosapien,dc=net"
ldap_modify: Undefined attribute type (17)
        additional info: aci: attribute type undefined
```

I must be doing something wrong or mentioning a wrong objectclass, etc. The question is, should I really be doing everything in bdb.ldif or is this possible to add ACIs that way and whatever method is "recommended" in this case, what's a better way to provide the ACIs I need to allow a user to change their own password (without the need of the directory manager)?

Edit: I also noticed with the olcAccess lines, ldapsearch doesn't show the userPassword line from an anonymous search.

Comment: You need an empty line before each line starting with "dn:" LDIF separates entries by blank lines. dn: denotes the distinguished name of an entry and  needs to be the first line of each entry.

Comment: You say "OpenLDAP", but you add "aci"s? AFAIK ACIs are only defined for 389-DS, while OpenLDAP adds thise in the corresponding database definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that it's probably better to just do it the bdb.ldif way. What I did was like the above, but I made a few changes.

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange,loginShell by dn="cn=manager,dc=bromosapien,dc=net" write by anonymous auth by self write by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by dn="cn=manager,dc=bromosapien,dc=net" write by group.exact="cn=LDAPADMIN,ou=Group,dc=bromosapien,dc=net" write by * read
```

What I did instead was, I labeled each line with braces and a number. I also added the ability for a user to change their login shell (because I allow Bash, ksh, and zsh, we default to bash). I then created a groupOfNames container inside of the Group OU. Like this.

```
dn: cn=LDAPADMIN,ou=Group,dc=bromosapien,dc=net
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
cn: LDAPADMIN
member: uid=zera,ou=People,dc=angelsofclockwork,dc=net
member: uid=sithlord,ou=People,dc=angelsofclockwork,dc=net
```

Of course, this requires the memberOf overlay.

The memberOf overlay I used is below:

```
% vi modules.ldif

dn: cn=module,cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module
olcModulePath: /usr/lib64/openldap
olcModuleLoad: memberof

% vi memberof.ldif

dn: olcOverlay=memberof,olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcMemberOf
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcConfig
objectClass: top
olcOverlay: memberof
olcMemberOfDangling: ignore
olcMemberOfRefInt: TRUE
olcMemberOfGroupOC: groupOfNames
olcMemberOfMemberAD: member
olcMemberOfMemberOfAD: memberOf
```